# Multiple dataset for single tablix in ssrs 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am working on ssrs which uses a table. I need to get values into the table from two dataset which comes from single datasource.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the over all table data set to one of the data sets which is used maximum to pull in the values to the table. For columns which has to use the second data set, in the Expression properties window, select the Dataset from the Catogery list and then you can select the dataset name and the valuew associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you're using SSRS 2008 **R2** you can use the Lookup() function in an expression in your table to pull in values from other datasets based on a lookup key or other joinable field.  Lookupset() would allow you to retrieve multiple records at once if you need to deal with a 1:many relationship.

See here for more:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx

This will not work if you're on plain old 2008.